# scikit-learn/python3 on raspberry pi

Tags: gcc, python-3.x, scipy, raspberry-pi, scikit-learn

I am trying to install http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html# on raspbmc. AND I would like to use python3. 
Since scikit-learn supports only python3 > 3.3, and pi comes with 3.2 I need to build everything.

So I built python 3.4, 
added pip to proceed with other builds/installs
using pip built numpy (one of scikit-learn dependency)

I am stuck on building scipy (one more scikit-learn dependency)
scipy build failed with gcc being terminated and suggestion to file gcc bug report. 
I tried newer gcc (4.8 instead of 4.6 that came with raspbmc) and got the same error.

Before I start digging into gcc and scipy build script:
Is there an easier way to get scikit-learn/python3 on raspberry pi?

Thank you!

P.S. I realize this is not purely programming Q, but scikit-learn site points to stackoverflow as a place for questions.

Comment: Hi Dima, the way I did it on my Pi was with http://continuum.io/downloads#34 they now have a 3.4 version and the typical 2.7. Good luck.

Comment: I second that. Don't try to compile scipy if you don't have to. There are several good scientific python distributions around, and anaconda, which @KLDavenport suggests is the one I usually recommend.

Comment: Thank you! I read about anaconda and got impression they do not have distribution for ARM processors. KLDavenport, did you use install for Linux-64? http://repo.continuum.io/anaconda3/Anaconda3-2.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh. The only thing I found about installing anaconda on pi is this post http://continuum.io/blog/raspberry and it seems to be with python 2.7 and very limited set of packages.

Comment: This is the answer from Continuum Analytics:
Hello Dima,
we are currently not planning to support Python 3 for the Raspberry PI.  The Python 2.7 we did a year and a half ago was only done because of PyCon 2013.  We currently do not actively support packages for the Raspberry PI.

Regards   Ilan

Comment: Tried again with new Raspbian (Jessie). It was slightly faster because I did not need to build python 3.4, but eventually I hit the same problem with gcc building scipy. Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77662

Answer (score 3):

Install Raspbian Jessie Lite, and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy python3-pip
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn
```

Run scikit-learn tests:

```
sudo pip3 install nose
sudo nosetests -v sklearn
```